# Unable to save to database from Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

There are no errors but the form doesn't save to database. Otherwise, its possible to add data from django admin.

The urls and redirects also work well, i can be able to open the form, edit/put data and hit submit, but the database does not reflect.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class RPAS(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '')
    serial_no = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default='')
    reg_mark = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.rpas.manufacturer

# RPAS.profile = property(lambda u: RPAS.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

def edit_rpas_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = RPAS(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(edit_rpas_profile, sender=User)
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import RPASForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def edit_rpas(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = RPASForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(commit=False)
                    return redirect ('/account/rpas/')

            else:
                form = RPASForm(instance=request.user)
                args = {'form': form}
                return render(request, "accounts/edit_rpas.html", args)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.forms import ModelForm
from accounts.models import RPAS

class RPASForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RPAS
        fields = (
        'manufacturer',
        'model_name',
        'serial_no'
        )
```

**template**

```
<form action="." method="POST" class="padding">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.as_p }}

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**and finally this is my admin.py**

```
from .models import RPAS
class RpasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('manufacturer','model_name','reg_mark','serial_no')

    def user_info(self, obj):
        return obj.description

admin.site.register(RPAS, RpasAdmin)
```

Comment: commit=False means won't save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving with `commit=False`, so the instance is never saved to the database. Remove it. You should also pass in the `RPAS` instance, not the `User`, since the form is for the `RPAS` model.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RPASForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.rpas)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('/account/rpas/')
else:
    form = RPASForm(instance=request.user.rpas)
```

You only need `commit=False` if you want to edit the object before saving, for example to set the `user` field. You don't need to do that in this case, because the `user` field is already set.

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
    return redirect ('/account/rpas/')
```

Comment: Thank you!! it works. But  'form = RPASForm(instance=request.user.rpas)' only works because the userprofile and rpas models are in the same app. I decided to move the RPAS model to another app. now i get the error that user has no attribiute rpas when using 'form = RPASForm(instance=request.user.rpas)'

Comment: `request.user.rpas` works because you have a one to one field from `RPAS` to `User`, so you can also follow the relationship backwards. The two models don't have to be in the same app.